# Why contracts are renewed every year?

Tags: contract-law

Why is it often said in contracts that they renew automatically every year, instead of just saying that the contract is for an unlimited time duration?

Comment: Are you able to clarify what type of contract you're talking about?

Comment: If you are from the UK there is  a law which says that a contract must be reasonable, and one that lasts forever would be harder to persuade someone that it is reasonable. What is your jurisdiction?

Comment: My jurisdiction is Israel, but that does not matter. I ask about a few contracts which I found in Internet (and don't remember their jurisdiction). They are probably termed "Terms of Service"

Comment: @Terry why is it more reasonable under this law that a contract automatically renews rather than continues?

Comment: Dependant on what the contract covers it can be cancelled within a grace period, so it gives time to sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

The only year-based constraint that comes to mind for US contracts, is that any contract that will last longer than the span of a year has to be a written contract (cannot be oral).  Contracts can and do certainly last longer than a year.  In many contractual circumstances, it's appropriate to have a periodic assessment or "escape hatch" that either party can use to politely and reasonably unwind their position...and a calendar year is a convenient signpost.